# How to create language select in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm currently using symfony 3.2. and now i have a link like this :
http://link.com?lang=en and in config/parameters I have allowed_locales -en, -ru

How could i create a language switcher in twig template like this :

```
  <a href="#" class="locales">EN<img src="{{ asset('assets/images/arrow-down.svg') }}" alt="arrow" class="arrow-down" /></a>
                                <div class="locales-content" style="left:0;">
                                    <a href="#">Russian</a>
                                    <a href="#">English</a>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did in my application, feel free to adapt it to your needs. It creates a dropdown with two links that redirect to the same page, but change the `_locale` parameter. In case there is no route in the request, it creates two links that redirect to the homepage.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{% if app.request.locale == 'ru' %}Russian{% else %}English{% endif %} <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        {# Check if there is a route and some parameters in the request #}
        {% if app.request.get('_route') is not empty and app.request.get('_route_params') is not null %}

            {# English #}
            <a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">English</a>
            {# Russian #}
            <a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'ru'})) }}">Russian</a>

        {# If there is no route in the request, redirect to the homepage #}
        {% else %}

            {# English #}
            <a href="{{ path('homepage', {'_locale': 'en'}) }}">English</a>
            {# Russian #}
            <a href="{{ path('homepage', {'_locale': 'ru'}) }}">Russian</a>

        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</li>
```